# What is difference with server harddisk?

Tags: hard-drive

I want to know is there harddisk specially for server? What is the name of it?
If I am using home external harddisk to serve files for client, what is the difference with it when using server harddisk?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is business-class storage so expensive?](http://serverfault.com/questions/263694/why-is-business-class-storage-so-expensive)

Comment: While I don't know the specifics of your situation, if I were your client, I'd be **very** upset to know that you are serving their data out of your house.

Comment: Not really. Most web designers are not professional in their IT and quite some work from home or a home office.

Comment: @TomTom - working from home is quite different from serving files from home.

Comment: @ErikA but he does not say he works from home. He says he is using home external harddisc (compared to server harddisk). Sounds to me (with very broken english on his side) he just  got a "normal end user external disc" and now wonders what is different in server level discs, not like he is SERVING them from home. He does not actually say anything about SERVING - I read this more like "I use a normal USB drivefor client files" but I may interpret too much here. I dont see a "I have a server" here in "Server" - that would have enough internal disc space.

Answer (score 2):

> I want to know is there harddisk specially for server?

There are *many* special hard dics for servers.

> What is the name of it?

I want to know if there is special car for taxi drivers. What is name of it?

There are more than one. All major manufacturers have enterprise rated lines.

> If I am using home external harddisk to serve files for client, what is the difference 
>   with it when using server harddisks?

The way you ask: none. Enterprise hard disks are not a lot more reliable, and without good backups you just risk your business.

Enterpise disks are normally made for running in servers. That is not "I have 2 disks in a home computer" but "I have a database server that is not a joke and needs a lot of IO and runs 24/7". They are FAST (up to 15.000 RPM) and allow a lot of parallel commands (SAS, not SATA - SAS is a network for disks, so to say, you can plug in SATA discs) and more resilient (SATA allows 2 connections which often go through different chips and cables, so even if a controller fails the computer can access the data through the second controller). They oten also come with larger warranties and are rated for 24/7 - normal disks may loose warranty if used so long. They normally get used in SAN scenarios r larger server... like I have a smaller database / virtual server with 24 disk slots which soon gets upgraded to a 72 disks.

But if you run a single disk on a USB external case then - you know - all the talks abou enterprise discs are like putting a formula 1 engine into a fiat panda - makes no sense.

Especially because of one thing: they also fail. You are a lot better off starting to think about backups *first*. Backups like onto Blue Ray media (128 GB doable) or tapes.